# Rails update PUT with same URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling a random `Post` and allowing users to +1 or -1 the post before loading another post. My model generates a random record at the URL /posts/random using the following.

**Post.rb // Model**

```
def self.find(*args)
  if args.first.to_s == "random"
    Post.find :first, :offset => rand(Post.count)
  else
    super
end
```

This code generates a random post when the user visits posts/random. However, I also defined a `thumbs_up` and `thumbs_down` field in the database that correspond to a `thumb_up` and a `thumb_down` image that when clicked, need to +1 or -1 the value in the database, before redirecting to another /posts/random. My understanding is that to do this I need to invoke the PUT update method, however, since my URL is posts/random instead of posts/1, how can I do this? Do I need to alter my routes?

Comment: You seem to be missing an `end`.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you, that was a copy error. This part works well to generate a random post from the database. My question is can I invoke the PUT update in spite of my fixed URL?

Comment: I generated a jQuery script to do a similar task (e.g. it called out to the put method with the param being changed) but I am not sure that was "the right way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that you'd need is an instance variable representing the random post so that you could use it in the thumbs up and thumbs down links.  Then you need to make sure that those links look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Thumbs Up", post_path(@post, thumbs_up: 1), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "Thumbs Down", post_path(@post, thumbs_down: 1), method: :put %>
```

That way, when in your update action for your posts controller, you can do something like this:

```
@post.update_attributes(thumbs_up: @post.thumbs_up + params[:thumbs_up],thumbs_down: @post.thumbs_down + params[:thumbs_down] )
```

That is only a start, but I think that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! I love Rails and the community surrounding it.